# How to re-write the part of code (spare_parts) to scrape all data

Tags: web-scraping, error-handling

Can someone help me with the part of the code - spare_parts?
When I create a dictionary and export to excel, I don't get all of the data.
But when I use print (commented) for Spare_part_number, Spare_part_name and Price, the terminal writes me all of them. Where is the problem?
.................................

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import xlsxwriter

baseurl = 'https://www.roco.cc/'

headers = {
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, sdch',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8',
    'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36',
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Cache-Control': 'max-age=0',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
}

productlinks = []

for x in range(1,2):
    r = requests.get(
        f'https://www.roco.cc/ren/products/locomotives/steam-locomotives.html?p={x}&verfuegbarkeit_status=41%2C42%2C43%2C45%2C44')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')
    productlist = soup.find_all('li', class_='item product product-item')
    
    for item in productlist:
        for link in item.find_all('a', class_='product-item-link', href=True):
            productlinks.append(link['href'])
    


Loco_list = []
Spare_parts_list = []

for link in productlinks:
    r = requests.get(link, allow_redirects=False)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')
    Manufacturer_name = 'Roco'
    
    try:
        Reference = soup.find('span', class_='product-head-artNr').text.strip()
    except:
        Reference = ''
        
    try:  
        Price = soup.find('div', class_='product-head-price').text.strip()
    except:
        Price = ''
        
    try:    
        Type = soup.find(
        'div', class_='product-head-name').h1.text.strip()
    except:
        Type = ''

    try:
        Scale = soup.find('td', {'data-th': 'Scale'}).text.strip()
    except:
        Scale = ''

    try:  
        Current = soup.find('td', {'data-th': 'Control'}).text.split(' ')[0]
    except:
        Current = ''


    try:  
        Control = soup.find('td', {'data-th': 'Control'}).text.strip()
    except:
        Control = ''

    try:
        Interface = soup.find('td', {'data-th': 'Interface'}).text.strip()
    except:
        Interface = ''

    try:
        Digital_decoder = soup.find(
            'td', {'data-th': 'Digital decoder'}).text.strip()
    except:
        Digital_decoder = ''

    try:
        Decoder_Type = soup.find(
            'td', {'data-th': 'Decoder-Type'}).text.strip()
    except:
        Decoder_Type = ''

    try:
        Motor = soup.find('td', {'data-th': 'Motor'}).text.strip()
    except:
        Motor = ''

    try:
        Flywheel = soup.find('td', {'data-th': 'Flywheel'}).text.strip()
    except:
        Flywheel = ''

    try:
        Minimum_radius = soup.find(
            'td', {'data-th': 'Minimum radius'}).text.strip()
    except:
        Minimum_radius = ''

    try:
        Length_over_buffer = soup.find(
            'td', {'data-th': 'Length over buffer'}).text.strip()
    except:
        Length_over_buffer = ''

    try:
        Number_of_driven_axles = soup.find(
        'td', {'data-th': 'Number of  driven axles'}).text.strip()
    except:
        Number_of_driven_axles = ''

    try:
        Number_of_axles_with_traction_tyres = soup.find(
        'td', {'data-th': 'Number of  axles with traction tyres'}).text.strip()
    except:
        Number_of_axles_with_traction_tyres = ''

    try:
        Coupling = soup.find('td', {'data-th': 'Coupling'}).text.strip()
    except:
        Coupling = ''

    try:
        LED_lighting = soup.find(
            'td', {'data-th': 'LED lighting'}).text.strip()
    except:
        LED_lighting = ''

    try:
        Head_light = soup.find('td', {'data-th': 'Head light'}).text.strip()
    except:
        Head_light = ''

    try:
        LED_head_light = soup.find(
            'td', {'data-th': 'LED head light'}).text.strip()
    except:
        LED_head_light = ''

    try:
        Country = soup.find(
            'td', {'data-th': 'Original (country)'}).text.strip()
    except:
        Country = ''

    try:
        Railway_company = soup.find(
            'td', {'data-th': 'Railway Company'}).text.strip()
    except:
        Railway_company = ''

    try:
        Epoch = soup.find('td', {'data-th': 'Epoch'}).text.strip()
    except:
        Epoch = ''

    try:
        Description = soup.find(
            'div', class_='product-add-form-text').text.strip()
    except:
        Description = ''


    Locomotives = {
        'Manufacturer_name': Manufacturer_name,
        'Reference': Reference,
        'Price': Price,
        'Type': Type,
        'Scale': Scale,
        'Current': Current,
        'Control': Control,
        'Interface': Interface,
        'Digital_decoder': Digital_decoder,
        'Decoder_Type': Decoder_Type,
        'Motor': Motor,
        'Flywheel': Flywheel,
        'Minimum_radius': Minimum_radius,
        'Length_over_buffer': Length_over_buffer,
        'Number_of_driven_axles': Number_of_driven_axles,
        'Number_of_axles_with_traction_tyres': Number_of_axles_with_traction_tyres,
        'Coupling': Coupling,
        'LED_lighting': LED_lighting,
        'Head_light': Head_light,
        'LED_head_light': LED_head_light,
        'Country': Country,
        'Railway_company': Railway_company,
        'Epoch': Epoch,
        'Description': Description,
    } 

    Loco_list.append(Locomotives)

# print(Locomotives)



    Spare_part_list = soup.find_all(
    'table', class_='data table additional-attributes')
    # print(Spare_part_number_list)
    # Spare_part_number_links = []

    for item in Spare_part_list:
        for Spare_part_number in item.find_all('td', {'data-th': 'Art. No.:'}):
            Spare_part_number = Spare_part_number.text.strip()
            # print(Spare_part_number)
        
        for Spare_part_name in item.find_all('td', {'data-th': 'Description'}):
            Spare_part_name = Spare_part_name.text.strip()
            # print(Spare_part_name)
        
        for Spare_part_price in item.find_all('td', {'data-th': 'Price:'}):
            Spare_part_price = Spare_part_price.text.strip()
            # print(Spare_part_price)

        
        Spare_parts = {
                    # 'Manufacturer_name': Manufacturer_name,
                    # 'Reference': Reference,
                    'Spare part number': Spare_part_number,
                    'Spare part name': Spare_part_name,
                    'Spare part price': Spare_part_price
                        }
        
        Spare_parts_list.append(Spare_parts)

            # print(Spare_parts)
#             Spare_parts.append(Spare_part_number_links)


   

df1 = pd.DataFrame(Loco_list)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(Spare_parts_list)
# # # df3 = pd.DataFrame()
# # # df4 = pd.DataFrame()
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('Roco - locomotives.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
df1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Model')
df2.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Spare parts')
# # # df3.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Documents')
# # # df4.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Photos')
writer.save()

print('Saved to file')
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it seems to be a duplicated of an already asked one (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74502975/missing-data-in-excel-from-2-products) - Instead of "spamming", it would be better to improve existing question. Take a minute to read: [ask] and How to create [mcve]. Would be great.

Comment: In addition to the comment above, may I suggest using a database to save the data? Use SQLite, have a table with locomotives, and another table with spare parts containing the foreign key for each locomotive. Save each record one by one, and you would surely see where the issue resides.

Comment: This is the same code, but another question.

Comment: It is neccesary to export the data in excel

Comment: If it is another, it should be focused exactly to the issue - Improving the question would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Try to simplify and focus your example - Issue with your spare parts is, that you just print a lot but overwrite. While using [`pandas`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/index.html) use its `pd.read_html` to get your goal:

```
#read et table, stripping not needed columns
spare_parts = pd.read_html(str(soup.select('#product-attribute-et-table')))[0].iloc[:,:3]

#add column with reference to product
spare_parts['Reference'] = soup.select_one('.product-head-artNr').text.strip()

#append dataframe to a list, that later could be concatinated
spare_part_list.append(spare_parts)
```

or iterate rows instead of coulmns in your `for-loop`.

##### Example

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

loco_list = []
spare_part_list = []

url = 'https://www.roco.cc/ren/products/locomotives/steam-locomotives.html?verfuegbarkeit_status=42%2C45%2C41%2C43%2C44'

for link in BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text).select('[id^="product-item-info_"]>a')[:3]:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(link.get('href')).text)

    d = dict(e.stripped_strings for e in soup.select('#product-attribute-specs-table tr'))
    d.update({'Reference': soup.select_one('.product-head-artNr').text.strip()})
    loco_list.append(d)
    
    spare_parts = pd.read_html(str(soup.select('#product-attribute-et-table')))[0].iloc[:,:3]
    spare_parts['Reference'] = soup.select_one('.product-head-artNr').text.strip()
    spare_part_list.append(spare_parts)

df1 = pd.DataFrame(loco_list)
df2 = pd.concat(spare_part_list, ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: can you please send me, where I can find some documentation for code what you wrote? I don't know how to work with this, when i need to do some changes

Comment: You are still working with`pandas` and `BeautifulSoup` so you should start there with reading documentation. *Personally, I think it would be great if a questioner at least showed some initiative and effort. Try it once, then you will also meet with a corresponding and much higher level of engagement in the answers. Always remember that it is your concern. Happy practising.*